# Why does my optimization (scipy.optimize.minimize) not work and return the initial values instead?

Tags: python, pandas, least-squares, minimize

I have a set of data; each column corresponds to a spectrum at a certain time. I want to fit the spectrum at a generic time (t_i) as a linear combination of the spectrum at time 0 (in the first column), at time 5 (in column 30) and time 35 (in column 210). So the equation I want to fit is:

### S(t_i) = a * S(t_0) + b * S(t_5) + c * S(t_35)

where:

1. 0 <= a, b, c <= 1
2. a + b + c = 1

I found the solution at this question ([Minimizing Least Squares with Algebraic Constraints and Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087336/minimizing-least-squares-with-algebraic-constraints-and-bounds)) super useful. But when I try it with my set of data the results are obviously wrong. I tried modifying the method to 'Nelder-Mead' but it doesn't respect my bound so I get negative values.

This is my script:

```
t0= df.iloc[:,0]    #Spectrum at time 0
t5 = df.iloc[:,30]  # Spectrum at time 5
t35 = df.iloc[:,120] # Spectrum at time 35
ti= df.iloc[:,20]
# Bounds that make every coefficient be between 0 and 1
bnds = [(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)]
# Constrain the sum of the coefficient to 1
cons = [{"type": "eq", "fun": lambda x: x[0] + x[1] + x[2] - 1}]
xinit = np.array([1, 0, 0])
fun = lambda x: np.sum((ti -(x[0] * t0 + x[1] * t5 + x[2] * t35))**2)
res = minimize(fun, xinit,method='Nelder-Mead', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
print(res.x)
```

If I use the Nelder-Mead method I get: `Out: [ 0.02732053  1.01961422 -0.04504698]` , if I don't specify the method I get:  `[1. 0. 0.]` (I believe that in this case the SLSQP method is being used).

The data I'm referring to is similar to the following:

```
0            3.333       5           35.001
0.001045089 0.001109701 0.001169798 0.000725486
0.001083051 0.001138815 0.001176665 0.000713021
0.001090994 0.001142676 0.001186642 0.000716149
0.001096258 0.001156476 0.001190218 0.00071286
```

Can you identify the problem? Can you suggest other ways to solve this problem? I have also tried using `least_squares`, but it failed.

Comment: Nelder-Mead does not take bounds or constraints. See the keywords at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Comment: If you need both you have to use `SLSQP` or `trust-constr`.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52438791/7919597

Comment: @Joe, I have tried SLSQP, but it gives wrong outputs. For example, by setting t_i = t5 which should give a=0, b=1 and c=0 but instead it gives 1, 0, 0. Using trust-constr I get better values but they are still wrong. I also read about this problem of Nelder-Mead that's why I'm having a hard time solving the problem.

Comment: These are local optimizers, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52438791/7919597 The suggestions are the same. Try different initial values for `x0`.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a local optimization strongly depends on the initial values.

It might return `[1, 0, 0]` for the case you stated above because there simply was no possibility for the optimizer to find a "downhill-only" way to `[0. 1. 0.]`. 
In fact, you might have started in a local minima and all ways out of the dip went uphill. So the optimizer chose to stay. That's how these optimizers work.

Try

```
xinit = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 0.0])
```

for `t_i = t5` and I am quite sure the optimizer will return the initial value.

For your case do what I stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52438263/scipy-optimize-gets-trapped-in-local-minima-what-can-i-do/52438791#52438791): Run the optimizer several times, each time pick random initial values inside your boundaries. You can pick the code posted there and just add your constraints, use SLSQP or trust-constr.